Creating a hierarchical view of custom elements in a MAUI App
I'm currently working on a MAUI application and I'm trying to implement a hierarchical view for my custom elements. Specifically, I want to allow users to collapse and expand elements, and have a clear view of which objects are children of others.
While I've researched various approaches, I haven't found a solution that fits my requirements.
I'd like to achieve a UI similar to the layout commonly found in file explorers or text editors/IDE's.
Additionally, I've tred getting help from some programming communities without success.
Could someone provide guidance or a code example on how to implement this hierarchical view in a MAUI app?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Use Expander from community toolkit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/expander. Just change the ui a bit have arrows on the left to show collapsed and expanded states.

There is no TreeView control in the .Net Maui. You may implement it yourself. There is a similiar issue which may help, Is there any control for tree view in .net MAUI?.
